# Is there a way to condense these two SQL queries into one query?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get the average number of products per user. To do this I have two queries:

One that gets the number of products:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `products`
```

And another that gets the number of users with products:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `users`.`id`) FROM `users` INNER JOIN `products` ON `users`.`id` = `products`.`creator_id`
```

So then I divide the number of products by the number of users to get an average. I would prefer to do this in one query, including the dividing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a regular `COUNT` to get the info;

```
SELECT COUNT(*) product_count, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT products.creator_id) user_with_product_count
FROM products
```

The product count is a plain row count, and to get the users with a product you can just count the distinct creators.

If you just want to calculate the average, just do the division between the counts right away;

```
SELECT COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT products.creator_id) average
FROM products
```

[A simple SQLfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25617/10).

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific but I meant I wanted to do the division in the query as well, this is the part I don't know how to do.

Comment: @Snubber Updated the answer with that too.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the count in, there might be better ways but ths works

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `products`) as OVERALL_COUNT,
COUNT(DISTINCT `users`.`id`) FROM `users` 
INNER JOIN `products` 
ON `users`.`id` = `products`.`creator_id`
```

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific but I meant I wanted to do the division in the query as well, this is the part I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Did you looking for this?

```
SELECT AVG( `products`.`id`)
FROM `users`
  INNER JOIN `products`
    ON `users`.`id` = `products`.`creator_id`
GROUP BY `users`.`id`
```